# What are the API endpoints for the Uber Eats service on android?

Tags: uber-api

I need to block access to the API endpoints used by the android application for Uber Eats at a DNS level, but there's no public documentation available for the Uber Eats service.

What are the API endpoints or hostnames associated with the Uber Eats service for the android application, I've managed to block their web app but not the android app.

Answer (score 1):

Blocking the following domains on my firewall has successfully stopped the uber eats app from functioning:

```
cn-geo1.uber.com
cn-dc1.geixahba.com
cn-dc1.shaipeeg.net
auth.uber.com
cn-dc1.oojoovae.org
cn-dc1.ooshahwa.biz
cn-dc1.naevooda.co
```